# HTACCESS not working as supposed

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting, web-hosting

i want to clean a couple of url's and it doesnt seem to work when i makes on my cpanel but it work when i test it on a xampp localhost

i want to change

```
http://www.technestng.com/?p=3
```

to

```
http://www.technestng.com/3
```

and i use this htaccess directive

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1/$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

and also i want to change

```
http://www.technestng.com/viewpost.php?id=reason-banks-struggle-with-the-implementation-of-big-data
```

to

```
http://www.technestng.com/reason-banks-struggle-with-the-implementation-of-big-data
```

And this is what i use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

this one works only when it is on top of the codes, right after RewriteEngine on but the issue is that when it does work, the navigation menus stops working

please help me out here

Comment: Obviously you have a pattern collision between `^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$` and `^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$`. So indeed the order of the rules is important. The first matching rule will apply. But that is nothing we can help with. You don't know your situation and code, this is something you will have to sort out yourself. Think along these lines: keep it simply and answer: what _exactly_ do I want to happen. Then proceed step by step.

Comment: Am really not good with htaccess, so I've been going to different forums and i try to understand what its all about after which i came up with this. so like you said ama keep it simply restart the process again

Comment: What I said is: you have to decide for yourself what rewriting should actually be applied. If you have _two_ rules with (practically) identical patterns following each other, then what sense does that make? In which order should they get applied? Why is it surprising that if you change the order, the other one applies?

Comment: Alright what i want to do is this that i want to make the pagination of my wedsite clean eg **www.technestng.com/5** instead of **www.technestng.com/?p=5** and also when an article is clicked it goes to **www.technestng.com/viewpost.php?id=article-name** but the url i want to appear is **www.technestng/article-name*** Can you help me please